# Binding a related model inside a partial and saving it

Tags: ember.js

I have a customer record and it in turn has an address.

template:

```
{{partial 'address-form' model=model.address}}
```

address-form partial:

```
{{input value=model.line1}}
```

Inside the partial I can do `{{log model.line1}}` and this works (it picks up the value entered into the input box).

However, back in the parent template I can do `{{log model.address.line1}}` but this results in `undefined`.

In the route, the address isn't populated:

```
window.console.log(this.currentModel.get('address')); //undefined
```

Regular attributes for the `currentModel` in the route do work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had neglected to instantiate the address model in the route's model hook:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    var customer = this.store.createRecord('customer');

    customer.set('address', this.store.createRecord('address'));

    return customer;
  }
}
```

The partial should also have been accessing the parent's scope's model directly.

```
{{input value=model.address.line1}}
```

Comment: calling this.args.model.save() in component still brings validation error on missing required relationship data. Where do you call the save?